# How do I push to git on the server?

Tags: git, apache, github

I've created a repo on a server with `git init`. It's located at `learning.example.com/gitdir/.git`

Now I'd like to push to it from my local computer, but I'm not understanding how to do this.

I created a local repo

`git init`

added a file (`index.html`)

```
git add index.html
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Now here's where I'm mixed up. My tutorial says to type `git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git`. So I tried:

```
git remote add origin git@learning.example.com/gitdir
git push origin master
```

...but after hanging for a while it gives me:

```
ssh: connect to host learning.example.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I'm pretty sure I have the right access rights, but I think maybe I'm just misunderstanding the path somehow.

**UPDATE**:

I've modified things a bit and I'm getting a slightly different error which makes me think I'm getting closer. Locally:

```
git remote add try6 ssh:myusername@learning.example.com:21098/public_html/learning/git
git push try6 master

myusername@learning.example.com's password: []
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

At least I logged in that time, right? I've tried a few variations on the path including `/public_html/learning/git.git`, `/git.git`, and `/git`.

Comment: ``git remote add origin ssh://yourGitRepoUrl/someRepo/project.git``. However the url does not have to end with ``.git``
The ``someName@`` would specify a default username but you can leave it out. Then you would have to enter a username on each connect followed by your password. Insteah of using the ``ssh://`` prefix you can also use the https-protocol.

Than make sure you have a git server running and in case you host it on your own check the port forwarding. You also should give sourcetree (free) a try. A graphical git-client.

Comment: So is `project` in your example the name of the folder? For me, it's in a folder named `git`. Or is `project` the name of the project? I don't think I've given it a name since all I did is `git init`.

Comment: Looks like sourcetree requires that my git repo be on either Bitbucket, Stash or GitHub. I don't see a way to connect to my own server as the remote.

Comment: the ``project.git`` is just an example. In general the url can look quite different. E.g. if you host your repo on bitbucket it will look like this: ``git@bitbucket.org:yourUserName/RepoName.git`` (where git@ does not stand for anything besides that you want to use the git service from bitbucket).

Comment: I'm hosting it on my own server, which is apache. The git repo is located at `learning.example.com/gitdir/.git`. So in this case, what would I put where you have `project.git`? Just `.git`? Nothing?

Comment: It depends on your git-server what the url looks like. However just ``.git`` seems akward. I guess it's something like ``/your_repo_name.git``. However thats pure guess-work right now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my repo doesn't have a name. I've literally only run `git init` and nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73815/discussion-between-newbee-and-lotstolearn).